# How to Leave Google Maps Lite Mode?

Tags: google-maps

I just used Google Maps, and as usual, I used the *help* icon to try and switch back to the Classic version.

Unfortunately, it brought me to a (new?) "Lite Mode" instead.

Now, I am wondering how I can at least leave that "Lite Mode" again and switch back to the full-fledged new Google Maps.

Things that I've tried:

- There is a lightning icon in the bottom right corner. When I click it, a popup says (in my native language): "You are using Lite Mode. Back to the full version of Google Maps.", where the last part of the text is a link. Unfortunately, clicking it does not cause any reaction.
- There is a link titled "Lite Mode" in the small info bar at the very bottom right, next to the source info on the map data. Clicking it brings to [a help page](https://support.google.com/maps/answer/6070247?p=litemode) that provides a button to return to the full Google Maps. Clicking it brings me back to Lite Mode.
- Restarting my browser and opening Google Maps anew still opens Lite Mode for me.
- [An answer on this site](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/57251/62455) suggests:

> Click this link to switch to full 3D mode: http://www.google.com/maps/preview/?force=webgl

Clicking that link brings me to Lite Mode.

**How do I leave Google Maps Lite and return to the full version of Google Maps?**

I am using Firefox 37.

EDIT: Meanwhile, I am using Firefox 39. The problem persists.